# Закодирование текста в Ascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Ни могу понять как закодировать в ascii(
Выдает

> b'Hello'

```
import codecs

def encrypto():
    encode_inf = 'Hello'
    en=codecs.encode(encode_inf,'ascii')
    print(en)

encrypto()
```

Comment: Собственно, такой вывод строкового литерала как раз и означает, что кодирование в ascii прошло успешно и всё нормально работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает без подключения модуля `codecs`. Просто замените:

```
en=codecs.encode(encode_inf,'ascii')
```

на:

```
encode_inf.encode('ascii')
```

Дальше вызывайте `print(encode_inf)`.
*Выводит: `Hello`*